# Can we inject compressed data to Kusto in plain text via Event Hub

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to ingest payload to Kusto/ADX via Event Hub

Limitation = 1 standard tier EH can only support throughput up to 40 Mbps.

Goal: Increasing max throughput by sending compressed payload without handling translation manually.

Example: payload = {
a: 1,
b: 2
}

we send this payload to EH by compression manually and Kusto store it as 1 row with 2 column a and b. Not handling compression handle from our end.

I am expecting Event hub to handle the compressed data and translation from their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's 40 MB (Mega**byte**) per second, not 40Mb (Mega**bit**).
2. You can compress your payload with gzip.
   Kusto will open it automatically as part of the ingestion process.

   [Ingest data from event hub into Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub)

   | Setting | Suggested value | Field description |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | Compression | None | The compression type of the event hub messages payload. Supported compression types: None, Gzip. |

Having said that, the right thing to do would probably be to switch to an Event Hubs in higher tier.

Comment: So if we are using httpclient to ingest our payload to event so can i just put message body as compressed string instead of json string?